# Matlab - Saving multiple variables from workspace in separate text files

Tags: matlab, save

How do I save multiple variables from workspace in separate text files with file name as the corresponding variable name?

Comment: Just curious, what's your use-case here? Text files are a pretty inefficient way to store data.

Comment: Use multiple calls to `save` function with different parameters.

Comment: @Suever: I use the them to plot in pgfplot. Please tell me if there is a better way of doing that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
vars = who;
for k = 1:numel(vars)
    save(vars{k},vars{k});
end
```

The `who` function grabs all of the variables in your current workspace and, in practice, could be replaced by a cell array of strings of just the variable names that you would like to save.